# SQL to LINQ convert

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, join

How can i convert from SQL as below to LINQ.

```
Select sum(detail.PO_Quantity) From PO_Master master     
left join PO_Detail detail on master.ID_PO = detail.ID_PO 
where master.PO_Status <> 21 And detail.PO_Item_Amount <> '0.00' And master.ID_PR = 'PR00010275'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var result = (from master in PO_Master
                     join detail in PO_Detail on master.ID_PO equals detail.ID_PO into md
                     from masterDetail in md.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where master.PO_STATUS != 21
                     && masterDetail.Item_Amount != "0.00"
                     && master.ID_PR == "PR00010275"
                     select masterDetail.Quantity).Sum();
```